# How to setup apache2 virtualhosts on your home directory on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to setup my apache2 virtualhost to run applications from an apps directory on my home directory.

```
home/myusername/apps/application1
```

Here are the steps there I am currently doing:

1) Creating the directories and adding an index.html file to it.

```
home/myusername/apps/application1/index.html
```

2) Granting Permissions to the directories.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/myusername/apps/application1

sudo chmod -R 755 /home/myusername/apps
```

3) Creating the virtual host file

```
sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/application1.app.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/myusername/application1
    ServerName application1.app
    ServerAlias www.application1.app

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

4) Activate the host

```
sudo a2ensite application1.app
```

5) Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

6) Adding the domain to the host file

```
127.0.0.1    application1.app
```

After doing all this, when I type the address on the browser application1.app I get the following 403.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at application1.app Port 80
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you use any non-standard directories with apache you need to also edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, and add in a `<Directory /bla/bla>` stanza so that apache knows it is OK to access the area. Just copy the existing `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` one. For example (from another question, and for a different location):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /media/newhd/test_web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yeah. That's right.. I figured out.. the instructions were on the apache2 landing page. Thanks tough. Voting up. ;)

Comment: There's a typo in the above answer, I tried to edit it but needs at least 6 characters to make an edit, and I don't have enough reputation to post a comment. /etc/apache2/apcahe2.conf should be /etc/apache2/apache2.conf