# Apache2 - Virtual Host - Error 404 Not Found

Tags: apache2

Just installed Apache2 on a dev box, no accessible from the Internet.
After the install I can open a browser from my client (MAC) to the IP Address and it does display the default "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page".

I am trying to setup a virtual host.
Found lots of references, but can't seem to make this work.

In the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` I created a `audio-site.conf` it has the following

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/jason/web

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/jason/web/>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then ran commands

```
sudo a2ensite audio-site
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

In the client browser I am trying to access using `http://IP-address/audio-site`.
I have tried several different settings based on researching this but nothing seems to work.

Any assistance on what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: This is duplicate. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617190/how-to-setup-apache2-virtualhosts-on-your-home-directory-on-ubuntu-14-04/617197#617197)

Answer (score 9):

That's not how virtual hosts work, I'm afraid ;) Virtual hosts are used to host multiple independent sites on the same web server.

"Back in the day", one machine hosted one website under one address. Say, your webserver hosts the website "www.my-site.tld". The files for that site (html, css, javascript, images, scripts, ...) are stored at `/var/www/`. Therefore, in the Apache config the `DocumentRoot` would be set to that directory, `/var/www/`.

If you now pointed your browser to `http://www.my-site.tld/welcome.html`, it'd display the file `/var/www/welcome.html`. To structure your site, you could use subfolders. So, for example, if you pointed your browser to `http://www.my-site.tld/holidays/summer2001.html`, it'd display the file `/var/www/holidays/summer2001.html`.

So far so good. But what if you wanted to host more than one website on the same machine, on the same host? Multiple websites under different addresses, that are (if you look at them "from the outside") competely independent from each other, not just different subdirs inside the same website? That's where virtual hosts come into play.

In a virtual host configuration you can set many directives not globally for the whole webserver, but *per website*. Say, you're hosting two websites on the same webserver, "www.my-site.tld" and "www.my-other-site.tld". For that, you can use two virtual host configurations, for example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site/
  ServerName www.my-site.tld
  ServerAlias my-site.tld
  DirectoryIndex welcome.html
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my-site.access.log "combined"
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my-site.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my-other-site/
  ServerName www.my-other-site.tld
  ServerAlias my-other-site.tld
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my-other-site.access.log "combined"
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my-other.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

You see, the `DocumentRoot` is defined differently in each virtual host, same for the `ServerName`, same for the `ServerAlias` and so forth.

I hope I could illustrate the idea of virtual hosts, and why virtual hosts and subdirectories inside the same host are two different things. To make it even more complicated, you can have subdirs inside a virtual host ;) Say, the address `http://www.my-other-website.tld/tournaments/finals2015.html` with the above config would point to `/var/www/my-other-site/tournaments/finals2015.html`.

Some other things you might come across, but that I can't go into in detail here:

If you're using addresses, domain names and such, you need to make sure that everybody knows where to find them. Just setting `ServerName my-cool-site.com` doesn't let "the internet" now where to direct requests for `my-cool-site.com` to ;) For that you'd typically use DNS by buying (in fact, it's mostly more *renting*, because you need to renew it every so often) the domain name and setting up a dns entry to the effect "if anybody's looking for `my-cool-site.com`, send them to server such and such".

When you use an ip address instead of a domain name, for example `http://127.0.0.1/webstuff/how-dns-works.html`, it doesn't change the principles shown above. In fact, if your server has assigned multiple ips to it, you can differentiate them in your virtualhosts. `<VirtualHost *:80>' means "apply this to requests for any ip, on port 80". If your server has`192.168.2.101`and`192.168.2.102`assigned to it, you can differentiate between those ips in your virtual hosts.`would only apply for requests directed to192.168.2.101`, not for requests directed to`192.168.2.102`.

If you want to call your webserver from the same machine it's running on and don't want to use an ip directly, you can typically just say "Show me the webpage on the same host I'm on now, on the local host". For that, typically the special hostname `localhost` is configured. So you could type something like `http://localhost/thats-a-long-answer.html' into your browser's address field.

Typically you have a common "parent directory" where all your virtual hosts `DocumentRoot`s are under. For example, you could have all your virtual hosts as subdirs of `/var/www/`. It's not strictly necessary do use that structure, but it has proven to help you keep track of things, in contrast to storing your websites all over the place ;)

To include a directory from outside a virtual host's `DocumentRoot`, you can use an `Alias`. Say, you add to the virtual host config of "www.my-site.tld" a directive like

```
Alias /sports /home/john/some-sports
```

In that case, `http://www.my-site.tld/sports/soccer.html` would point to `/home/john/some-sports/soccer.html`.

But such cases are prone for permission problems. The files in `/home/john/some-sports` are typically owned by the user `john`, so the user your webserver software (Apache) is running as may not have access to them.

All that might be a bit much do digest all at once, but those are some of the basic concepts you need to understand to successfully run a webserver. It's not as complicated as it might seem on the first glance.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed information. I tried to use the virtual host example shown but still received the 404 error. So I decided to take the directory approach so under /var/www/html moved $HOME/audio-site under this directory. I am able to access the index.html using http://IP-ADDR/audio-site.