# don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I would like to change my apache root server ( **/var/www >>> /media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites** ). For that directory path has been changed from /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory "/media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Edited also VirtualHost file located /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

Edited code below :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName wp.local
        DocumentRoot "/media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites/wp"
        ServerAlias www.wp.local

</VirtualHost>
```

After putting all changes , all services  also restarted.

Then I hit http://localhost or http://wp.local and showing this forbidden message :

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: When you use non-standard directories you also have to allow such in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617190/how-to-setup-apache2-virtualhosts-on-your-home-directory-on-ubuntu-14-04/617197#617197).

Answer (score 1):

The user 'www-data' needs at least read permissions (and for wordpress, write permissions) for the `/media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites/` directory. Run the following at a command line:

`chgrp -R www-data /media/mhsoha11/Local\ Disk/Sites`

`chmod -R 664 /media/mhsoha11/Local\ Disk/Sites`

This changes the group to the web server and gives the web server read and write permissions recursively to all files and directories under `/media/mhsoha11/Local\ Disk/Sites` inclusive.

Comment: when put this command , showing below output :

mhsohag11@MHS:~$ chgrop www-data /media/mhsoha11/Local\ Disk/Sites

Command 'chgrop' not found, did you mean:

  command 'chgrp' from deb coreutils
  command 'chprop' from deb karma-tools

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Comment: Sorry that is not correct. See my edit

Comment: your instruction have been followed . Then i restarted apache2 and try again but can't access yet ! Showing list of folder with permission value

mhsohag11@MHS:/media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites$ ls -al
total 28
drwxrwxrwx 1 mhsohag11 mhsohag11     0 Apr 20 17:29 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 mhsohag11 mhsohag11 28672 Apr 20 17:26 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 mhsohag11 mhsohag11     0 Apr 30 10:02 wp
mhsohag11@MHS:/media/mhsohag11/Local Disk/Sites$

Comment: In apache2.conf, try removing the quotes from the <Directory /path/to/root> tag. You will probably need to escape the space so it looks like: <Directory /media/mhsoha11/Local\ Disk/Sites/>. Also, remove the quotes from DocumentRoot in sites-available. Just for kicks run `a2ensite 000-default` as well. It looks right to me otherwise. Then restart apache `apachectrl restart` or `systemctl restart apache2`.