# Problem installing apache webserver: “You don't have permission to access this resource.” on http://localhost/

Tags: apache2, partitioning, webserver

I installed a new version of Ubuntu on my computer. Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

The files for my website are on another disk. See *Program Tools* → *Disks*

- Device: `/dev/sdb1`
- Partition type: Linux
- Contence: Ext4(versie 1.0) – Mounted on `/media/joris/doc`

I did following ( [source](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache#1) ):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo cp 000-default.conf gci.conf

sudo gedit gci.conf
DocumentRoot media/joris/doc/website

sudo a2ensite gci.conf
service apache2 reload

sudo adduser joris  www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/joris/doc/website
sudo chmod -R g+rw /media/joris/doc/website
```

P.S. I live in Belgium and I speak Dutch. Exist also a dutch forum
 of Ubuntu?

I have taken new steps I encountered problems with rights in other programs

```
mkdir /d sudo cp etc/fstab etc/fstab_oud
sudo gedit etc/fstab

# Harde schijf 1TB
UUID="23f455e3-08a4-4e34-9122-19e375ed6a4c" /d ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Folder website: `/d/website`

```
cd etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo gedit gci.conf

# DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  DocumentRoot /d/website

sudo gedit etc/apache2/apache2.conf Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted
```

With the program dolphin I added a named user `www-data`

I have added named user `www-data` and [v] Apply changes to all subfolders and their content

```
service apache2 reload
```

My site is still not displayed, but the default site of apache!

Comment: I shouldn't add it here, but yes, there is a [dutch forum](https://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/) of Ubuntu, you can find it with a 5 seconds search

Comment: Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617190/how-to-setup-apache2-virtualhosts-on-your-home-directory-on-ubuntu-14-04/617197#617197)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup apache2 virtualhosts on your home directory on ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617190/how-to-setup-apache2-virtualhosts-on-your-home-directory-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved!!

I did this:

```
joris@joris-MS-7798:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo a2dissite 000-default
[sudo] wachtwoord voor joris:
Site 000-default disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
systemctl reload apache2
joris@joris-MS-7798:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo a2ensite gci.conf
Site gci already enabled
joris@joris-MS-7798:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

And it worked!!

Comment: So what was the problem? Did you edit `gci.conf` in between? Or did you just forget `sudo` in your original `service apache2 reload` command?